# "Маша" или "девочка"

Tags: стилистика

**Вы**: Привет! Как вчера день провёл?

**Ваш собеседник**: Привет! Весь день гулял с (*Машей* /*со знакомой девочкой*)

Вопрос: уместно ли упоминать имя неизвестного собеседнику человека (собеседник не знает кто такая Маша) или лучше использовать слово подруга/девочка и т.д.?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! Your question is interesting, but it's not quite fit for this site. It's not specific to Russian, it would be as valid in English or any other language I'm aware of. It would make a good question for https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/ had it been asked in English. Do you want to translate this question to English so that I could move it there? You will probably get a much better answer there.

Comment: Hi, Quassnoi!  Thank you, and İ would be ever so grateful if you could do that! Should İ rewrite the question or it is fine as is?

Comment: You can just go there and ask a new question in English, and close this one; or edit this one and ask me to move. It's up to you.

Comment: Got it, thanks again:)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Нет, называть по имени незнакомых собеседнику людей неуместно. Первое требование к речи - чтобы она была понятна для слушающего. Откуда собеседник знает, кто такая Маша - это может быть подруга говорящего, его родственница, маленькая девочка, с которой его попросили погулять или даже собака.

Comment: User31264, Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: I have deleted some derogatory comments. Please stay civil. Thanks.

Comment: Называть незнамых людей по имени можно, но необходимо их при этом представить, например: "Весь день гулял с Машей, она моя девушка."

Comment: @Alexander - да, согласен, но имхо лучше сначала назвать их роль, потом имя - весь день гулял с моей девушкой, её зовут Маша

Comment: user31264  а также плепорции... ну там, 90-60-90...

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос, совершенно очевидно - не лингвистический.
Разумеется, в русском языке из слова "Маша" вывести факт, что это лицо женского пола - семантически-логически возможно. Вывести из "подруга/девушка", что это была именно Маша - нет.  Грамматически всё это допустимо. :>

А что кому говорить или не говорить - вы решите сами.

Comment: Если он не лингвистический, то какой тогда?:) Как Вы, вообще, понимаете слово "Лингвистика"? Есть просодия, семантика, прагматика, стилистика...более того, ранее я уже разъяснил лингвистическую ценность этого вопроса. И вообще, при чём здесь вообще семантика?

Comment: вот это вот - "уместно ли .." и т.д.  - это не лингвистический вопрос. :)  И в моем ответе выше всё сказано.  Нет, слово "лингвистика" я не понимаю ни как "правила хорошего викторианского тона", ни как "пуританский Катехезис", ни как дипломатию или "инструкции по обучению детсадовцев", и ничего подобного... Стилистика тоже никому не навязывает никаких именно такого рода "уместно ли". :>
"Если он не лингвистический, то какой тогда?:" - представления не имею, и не понимаю, зачем он вообще нужен. :>>

"

Comment: "в моем ответе выше всё сказано" в Вашем ответе лишь сказано, что Вы имеете крайне размытое понятие  того, что представляет собой наука "логика", и что глубина Вашего понимания языка ограничена исключительно его практическим бессознательным применением (тот факт, что Вы смогли написать слово "Катехезис" без ошибок, не означает, что Вы имеете представление о том, что из себя представляет грамматическая категория определённости). Если муравей не имеет представления о том, зачем люди запускают спутники в космос - это проблема  исключительно муравья :>> Если вопрос задан, значит кому-то это надо.

Comment: нууу, если это был муравей... тогда понятно.